# pd.to_datetime to unix timestamp to date in python is giving incoreect output

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run this code.

```
raw_data['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(raw_data['UNIX Timestamp'],origin='1970-01-01', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The conversion of the date is incorrect.

```
Unix Timestamp  Date
1546369086  1/1/1970
1546369125  1/1/1970
1546375732  1/1/1970
1546334013  1/1/1970
1546340971  1/1/1970
1546367135  1/1/1970
1546367286  1/1/1970
1546367295  1/1/1970
```

However, when i use the below code, it is giving me correct result.

```
import datetime
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1546369086)
print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
2019-01-02 00:28:06
```

Comment: Please update your question with the result you're getting as well as the result you expect.

Comment: This does not make sense. Please provide some input data. the `origin` argument is used when you have numeric values (i.e. number of seconds since some date), while you also provide a format string, indicating you almost certainly don't have a numeric input.

Comment: Sorry. Last time it didn't update properly. I have edited the quest. Thanks

Comment: Do not specify the format, that is used with string dates, you need: `pd.to_datetime(df['Unix Timestamp'], unit='s')`, which is explained in the dup

Comment: It still isn't giving the correct date. pd.to_datetime(raw_data['UNIX Timestamp'],unit='ms'). I tried adding origin '1970-01-01' but that also didn't help
Out[123]: 
0       1970-01-18 21:32:49.086
1       1970-01-18 21:32:49.125
2       1970-01-18 21:32:55.732
3       1970-01-18 21:32:14.013
4       1970-01-18 21:32:20.971

Comment: Why are you using `'ms'` as the unit? I specifically posted `'s'` 2 lines above. (Your numbers represent seconds since 1970-01-01, **not** milliseconds since 1970-01-01)

Comment: I am getting an error when I'm using 's'

Comment: OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input 1546367123676.0 with the unit 's'